# How to spell out a time duration down to seconds?

Tags: indications-de-temps, coordination, unités, formatage

I need French translation for "five hours thirteen minutes and eighteen seconds" (full phrase sounds like "the call lasted five hours thirteen minutes AND eighteen seconds").
GT translates it like "cinq heures treize minutes et dix-huit secondes" but I heard that it should be "cinq heures et treize minutes et dix-huit secondes".
Which variant is more correct?

Comment: <mode_trolling>J'espère qu'au moins, vous n'êtes pas anglais. sinon... nous avoir piqué l'heure sans savoir comment la dire... </mode_trolling> https://www.pourlascience.fr/sd/histoire-techniques/comment-la-france-adopta-lheure-de-greenwich-6322.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is correct, the second one is not. You should tell this like an enumeration, only putting "et" between the last part and the one before.

> 3 heures et 8 minutes
>
> 3 heures 8 minutes et 30 secondes
>
> 4 jours 3 heures et 30 secondes